# filling a list of objects from json in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to take an example project with static data and make it dynamic with a http call to an endpoint in flutter.

EDIT --- JSON CODE

```
Future<User> getUsers(String groupID ) async {

  final response =
  await http.post('http://url/api/GetUsers',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", 
             'Accept': 'application/json',},
  body: json.encode({'groupID' : groupID}));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   // If the call to the server was successful, parse the JSON
    User _users;
   _users = User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    return _users;
```

The format of the data is in is this:

```
List<Pokemon> _pokemonList = [
  Pokemon(id: 1, name: 'Bill Smith',type: 'Caregiver', image: 'assets/images/KC_logo.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 2, name: 'Joy Smith',type: 'Caregiver', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_2.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 3, name: 'Joe Smith',type: 'Member', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_3.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 4, name: 'Pete Smith',type: 'Member', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_4.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 5, name: 'Steve Smith',type: 'Caregiver', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_5.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 6, name: 'Paul Smith',type: 'Member', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_6.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 7, name: 'Balbasaur',type: 'Grass', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_7.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 8, name: 'Balbasaur',type: 'Water', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_8.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 9, name: 'Balbasaur',type: 'Rock', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_9.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 11, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Fire', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_11.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 12, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Rock', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_12.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 13, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Grass', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_13.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 14, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Water', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_14.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 15, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Fire', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_15.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 16, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Grass', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_16.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 17, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Fire', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_17.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 18, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Water', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_18.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 19, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Rock', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_19.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 20, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Fire', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_20.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 21, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'FiWaterre', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_21.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 22, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Grass', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_22.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 23, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Rock', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_23.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 24, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Grass', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_24.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 25, name: 'Pichu',type: 'Water', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_25.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 26, name: 'Charmender',type: 'Fire', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_26.png'),
  Pokemon(id: 27, name: 'Charlizard',type: 'Rock', image: 'assets/images/pokimon_27.png'),
 ];
 }
```

How can this be achieved in Dart?

Comment: Please explain more what you actually want to do? do you want to call api?

Comment: Yes I wil be calling a webAPI built in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

To call an API,

**Method 1**

> Use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) library

Call a get Request like this,

```
  var url = "https://www.your_api_url.com?query=a";

  // Await the http get response, then decode the json-formatted responce.
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var itemCount = jsonResponse['totalItems'];
    print("Number of books about http: $itemCount.");
  } else {
    print("Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.");
  }
```

**Method 2**

> Use [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) library

sample get request,

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
void getHttp() async {
  try {
    Response response = await Dio().get("http://www.your_api_url.com");
    print(response);
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

**Convert your json to dart model using [this tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/)**

Comment: I have that part working, I am having trouble with getting the response into the correct format.

Comment: Are you facing trouble to parse the json data? use [this tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to convert your json to dart. then do something like MyModel model = new MyModel.fromJson(dataConvertedToJSON);

Comment: I am successfully returning single objects from http into dart but the list is giving me trouble.

Comment: So I can load multiple results into that object? That would solve my issue for sure.

Comment: Yes have parent object as ```Class Parent{
List<JsonFormServerModel> list;
}``` something like this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202911/discussion-between-ravinder-kumar-and-sam-cromer).